Ishta Devta vs Upasana Devta
Namaskar,
Both those terms are very new to me. I tried searching this up, but couldn't get much answers.
Appreciate if my doubts below could be clarified.

Are both the same and if not, how do they differ.
Do we need to pray to both of them.
Can Ishta Devta be any deity that I feel connected to or this should be looked up against our birth chart.
When should one pray upon their Ishta Devta.

Thank you.

Ishta Devata is your favorite deity for whom you feel natural devotion and love. Any other deities you may worship to fulfill certain goals are Upasana devatas. There is nothing more in this.

Ishta means loved,desired and Upasana means worship.
